# How to get a String value from a Map <String, String[] > in Java?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

Basically, I have a `Map<String, String[] >` which contains a bunch of strings with a key. If I do `String value = myMap.get("keyName");`, this returns an `Object` rather than a string, and echoing it produces something like this: `Ljava.lang.String;@1dfa166`. Doing `toString()` doesn't help either.

What do I need to do to get the value as string:

My code looks like this:

```
String value ="" + request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("keyName");
```

Here the `asFormUrlEncoded()` method is what returns the `Map`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting back an array of strings (second parameter to the generic Map as declared).

Change it to

`String [] values = myMap.get( "keyName" );`

and check values.length to see how many strings are in the array.  If it's just one, you can just access it as `values[0]`.

The reason it allows for a string array is because each key in the form could have multiple values, so it can't return a single string.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it just as you posted your answer. Is there no quicker way to just get the first value?

Comment: Can I supply `<String, String>` as the parameter to the map to have the values supplied as a string?

Comment: You can parametrize the map with any two types you want, including <String, String>. If you'd like, you can also make it <Map<Integer, ServerSocket>, ArrayOutOfBoundException>.

Comment: See the java tutorial on generics on how to use those: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: I get the impression that map is created/built by 'asFormUrlEncoded()', which presumably you didn't author.  Declaring values to be Map< String, String > won't do conversion for you, if that's what you're asking.  It might be a bit painful to check for a single value, but you could always create a utility method to do it for you.